# Using sep when multiplying strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, separator

I've been told that in python 3.x it's possible to add a separator between strings that you repeat using multiplication, for example..

```
c = "rabble"

print(c * 5, sep = ' | ')
```

I would like it to print out "rabble" 5 times with the string `|` in between each repeat.

It keeps printing the repeated string, but without the separator character. I'm having trouble finding info regarding the use of sep in this specific situation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the effect you want, but it doesn't really have much to do with multiplication *per se*.

The `sep` argument to [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) provides a separator between the non-keyword arguments - for example:

```
>>> print("spam", "eggs", "ham", sep=" | ")
spam | eggs | ham
```

You could just pass `c` to `print()` 5 times to get the output you're looking for:

```
>>> c = "rabble"
>>> print(c, c, c, c, c, sep=" | ")
rabble | rabble | rabble | rabble | rabble
```

... but that's clunky, and no use if you don't know in advance how many times you'll want `c` to appear.

To get around this problem, you can use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) – a special syntax to pass a list or other sequence to a function as though the items in it were being passed as individual arguments:

```
>>> s = ["spam", "eggs", "ham"]
>>> print(*s)  # notice the *
spam eggs ham
```

To get the result you're looking for, you can construct a list on the fly from 5 copies of `c`, and pass that list with the argument unpacking notation:

```
>>> print(*([c] * 5), sep = ' | ')
rabble | rabble | rabble | rabble | rabble
```

Notice that you're multiplying a list containing `c` by five, rather than `c` itself. You might find it helpful to check out what `print(*(c * 5), sep = ' | ')` actually does, and to try and work out why (hint: strings are also sequences).

Comment: Thanks Zero, I tried the code at the end (using argument unpacking without putting c in a list) and it prints out each letter of the string "rabble" with the '|' string separating each one. I think I have a better understanding of the original problem, which is that print(c*5) simply concatenates 5 strings and provides no breaking point into which the '|' string can be inserted. When using argument unpacking, each letter is its own item, and in lists each string is its own item between both of which a separator can be inserted. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

print("rabble | "*5)

Comment: I don't think this can be a reliable solution.